# how to convert grouped dataframe multilevel index to datadict

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

sample dataframe:

```
                      avg
Key1       Key2
a1         b1          v1
           b2          v2
           b3          v3
a2         b4          v4
a3         b5          v5
           b6          v6
a4         b7          v7
```

How to convert this to a datadict
{a1:v1, a1:v2, a1:v3, a2:v4, a3:v5, a3:v6, a4:v7}

I tried this with no luck
dict(zip(df['ColA'], df['avg']))
Appreciate any help !!

Comment: I think the best way to solve this question is read the document.https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is multiple index using `get_level_values`

```
dict(zip(df.index.get_level_values(1), df['avg']))
```

Comment: Thanks !!compile error : _Cannot access attribute 'index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects_

Comment: @HpK why there is groupby object ? also For every question you ask you can select one of the answer mark as accept, check mark at the left(PS: your previous answer need accept one as well :-)  )

Comment: it is a DataFrameGroupBy because I  grouped by col1, col2, and avg is mean on the grouped col2